# Print existing document with Word automation

Tags: c#, automation, ms-word, word-automation

I want to print out word documents that I generated in my program. Therefore I use this code:

```
public static void druckeRechnung(object oFilename)
{
    object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    List<int> procIds = getRunningProcesses();
    _Application wordApp = new Application();
    wordApp.Visible = false;

    _Document aDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oFilename);

    try
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog pDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();
        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {                    
            wordApp.ActivePrinter = pDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
            wordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, 
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
                ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);                    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fehler beim Drucken");
    }
    finally
    {
        aDoc.Close(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);
        wordApp.Quit(WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges);

        aDoc = null;
        wordApp = null;

        killProcess(procIds);
    }
}
```

The first time I print a document it works just like it should, but after that the request is sent to the printer and nothing happens.

Am I doing anything wrong? Are there better ways to realize this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is that the document is closed before the print finished.

I added the WHILE before the document closes:

```
 var printDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog();

        if (printDialog.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            w. = printDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
            d.PrintOut();

        }

        while (w.BackgroundPrintingStatus>0)
        {

        }


        d.Close(false);
        w.Quit();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's been a little while since I worked on this project, but I will definitely try your approach!

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowing the process to complete the printing. To do this you will need to pause your code, to do this  you can use the first parameter of PrintOut.

```
object background = false;
wordApp.ActiveDocument.PrintOut(background, ref missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref  missing, ref missing,
    ref missing);
```

As the documentation says: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.printout(v=vs.80).aspx

"Background true to have the customization code continue while Microsoft Office Word prints the document."